# Is there any ways to use QR Codes for installing an app if it's not already installed, if it's installed redirecting to a specific screen in the app?

Tags: flutter, vue.js, qr-code, vuejs3, flutter-qrcode

I am trying to finish up my app which is written on flutter for iOS and VueJS for web version. Planning to use QR codes for installing an app if it's not already installed, if it's installed and user is not logged in, ask for the user's credentials and redirecting to a specific screen in the app, and if the user has installed the app and is logged in, redirect them to the specific page.
Since I have not ever used QR codes before and couldn't find anything helpful on the web, would like to know if it's even possible to do so.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [firebase_dynamic_link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) for this you can create links that redirect to specific screen .you can process this link and can redirect to specific screen within the app. The generated link can be added in a qr code which when scanned returns the link.